# Short story/novel from 90's or late 80's involving monsters called "Eaters"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What I remember of the book was: something happened and monsters called "Eaters" appeared and humans had to band together and use lights to keep them at bay.

It wasn't a very long book more like a short story I read in high school back in mid 90's.

I can't remember title but it was something like "a time of monsters" or something on that line.

Cover was black I believe with a skull with sharp teeth on a table, I believe.

Been over 20 years since I read it, but I do remember it has illustrated pages too.

Comment: In [Surface Tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Tension_(short_story)) by James Bliish humans are miniaturised and they call predatory rotifers "Eaters". This doesn't sound like your story though, and none of the anthologies [shown on the ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56266) have a cover with a skull.

Comment: The description made me think of [The Langoliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Past_Midnight#The_Langoliers)..  Not a 100% fit for the information in the OP but similar monster, not sure if they were described as Eaters in the novella though

Comment: Is reminding me of the [*Claymore*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claymore_(manga)) manga series.